# R-How to count the number of non-zero value in a column by year?

Tags: r, count

My table has four columns, 'year', 'doy', 'rain', and 'crain'. The column 'year' ranges from 1957-2007 and the column 'doy' ranges from 1-365(or366).

What I'm trying to know is:

For each year (1957-2007), how many rows has non-zero value in the column 'rain'?

For example, in 1957, I would like to know how many rows has non-zero value in the column 'rain'?

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Gloria

Comment: Seems like an aggregate problem - `aggregate(rain ~ year, data=dat, FUN=function(x) sum(x>0) )`

Comment: i deleted my answer after rereading your question, but also useful as an additional way to explore the data ad hoc: `nrow(subset(mydata, year==1957 & rain > 0))`

Comment: Thank you thelatemail and lispHK01. Is there anyway that I can calculate the number of rows for each year and list them together like: 1957 125, and the next row is 1958 129. etc...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a reproducible example. Try to ask your questions like this in the future.

```
data <- data.frame(sample(1957:2007, 1000, T), 
                   sample(1:365, 1000, T), 
                   round(rnorm(1000, 0, 10)))
names(data) <- c('year', 'day', 'rain')

# there are many ways to do this 
# credit to thelatemail - This uses ?aggregate
aggregate(rain ~ year, data=data, FUN=function(x) sum(x != 0))

# This approach uses split and sapply functions
sapply(split(data$rain, data$year), function(x) sum(x != 0))

# Using data.table package
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, list(rain=sum(rain != 0)), by=year]
```

Comment: Nice. `setDT(data)[, ...]` is more efficient.